# R plot type line wont work but point does

Tags: r, plot

I've got a dataframe which I want to plot with 2 diffenent y axes. Everything works fine, exept the type: 'line' of first graph "Grundwasserstand". However, chosing the type='point' the measurements are printed correctly in the plot. I guess the Problem is caused by the NA´s.

Nessesarily I need to get type='line' working.

What shall i do? Interpolation is no option in this case. Neither is leaving data from Elbewasserstand.

shown some rows of my dataframe:

```
Time Grundwasserstand Elbewasserstand
1   1980-01-01           119.62         110.576
2   1980-01-02               NA         111.426
3   1980-01-03               NA         111.316
4   1980-01-04               NA         111.126
5   1980-01-05               NA         110.956
6   1980-01-06               NA         110.786
7   1980-01-07               NA         110.726
8   1980-01-08               NA         110.866
9   1980-01-09               NA         110.816
10  1980-01-10               NA         110.756
11  1980-01-11               NA         110.656
12  1980-01-12               NA         110.636
13  1980-01-13               NA         110.316
14  1980-01-14               NA         110.176
15  1980-01-15           119.65         110.146
16  1980-01-16               NA         110.166
```

what my plot code Looks like:´

```
png(filename = speicherpfad_inkl_namen_png, width = 1000)
par(mar=c(5, 4, 2, 4) + 0.1)
plot(zusm$Time,zusm$Grundwasserstand, type = "b", 
           col="1", ylab = "Grundwasserstand [m NHN]", xlab = "Time", axes = T)
par(new=T)
plot(zusm$Time, zusm$Elbewasserstand, type = "l",col="blue", lwd=1,
           axes=F, ylab = "", xlab = "" ) 
axis(side = 4, col="black") 
mtext(4,text="Elbewasserstand [m NHN]", col = "black", line = 2)
legend("bottomright",title="Legende", legend = c("Grundwasserstand", "Elbewasserstand"), 
             lwd = 1, col = c(1,4))
dev.off()
```

UPDATE:

solved with Addition of:

```
zusm$Time[!is.na(zusm$Grundwasserstand)],zusm$Grundwasserstand[!is.na(zusm$Grundwasserstand)]
```

in my plot-code in plot nr. 1!

```
png(filename = speicherpfad_inkl_namen_png, width = 1000)
par(mar=c(5, 4, 2, 4) + 0.1)
plot(zusm$Time[!is.na(zusm$Grundwasserstand)],zusm$Grundwasserstand[!is.na(zusm$Grundwasserstand)], type = "l", 
         col="1", ylab = "Grundwasserstand [m NHN]", xlab = "Time", axes = T)
par(new=T)
plot(zusm$Time, zusm$Elbewasserstand, type = "l",col="blue", lwd=1,
         axes=F, ylab = "", xlab = "" ) 
axis(side = 4, col="black") 
mtext(4,text="Elbewasserstand [m NHN]", col = "black", line = 2)
legend("bottomright",title="Legende", legend = c("Grundwasserstand", "Elbewasserstand"), 
           lwd = 1, col = c(1,4))
dev.off()
```

Comment: You need to decide what you want to do with the NA values. What do you want the plot to look like?

Comment: Actually I want simply ignore them. I've already solved the Problem, shown in the update of my question.